# How to partition mysql table without adding partition column to Ptimary Key?

Tags: mysql, unique

I want to partition a very large table by a column that is neither part of the `primary key` nor part of the `unique keys`. Thus, I cannot create a partition as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE persons (
  id bigint NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  availability tinyint,
  firstname varchar(20),
  lastname varchar(20),
  dob date,
  PRIMARY KEY (id),
  KEY person_unique (firstname,lastname,dob),
)
PARTITION BY RANGE COLUMNS(availability) (
    PARTITION p_inactive VALUES LESS THAN (1),
    PARTITION p_active VALUES LESS THAN (MAXVALUE)
);
```

Result:

> A PRIMARY KEY must include all columns in the table's partitioning
> function (prefixed columns are not considered).

Question: is there any way partitioning, without having to include my partition column into the PK? Because in this example, the PK is autogenerated (thus not suitable to include the `availability column).

If not - what's the use of partitioning? If I anyways would have to add the partition columns into my PK, then I could as well just fetch the results furthermore without partitioning, because the index in PK would already lead to query optimization.

Comment: Why you can't include availability in PK ?

Comment: I could, but does it make sense? Why should a row be identified by the already unique `id` *plus* an additional field?

Comment: Check [24.6.1 Partitioning Keys, Primary Keys, and Unique Keys](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/partitioning-limitations-partitioning-keys-unique-keys.html).

Answer (score 1):

Yes it doesn't make sense for a PK but in Mariadb documentation a get an exemple of range partition type and they add the column used in partition. So you don't have choice I think.

```
CREATE TABLE log
(
    id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    timestamp DATETIME NOT NULL,
    user INT UNSIGNED,
    ip BINARY(16) NOT NULL,
    action VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id, timestamp)
)
    ENGINE = InnoDB
PARTITION BY RANGE (YEAR(timestamp))
(
    PARTITION p0 VALUES LESS THAN (2013),
    PARTITION p1 VALUES LESS THAN (2014),
    PARTITION p2 VALUES LESS THAN (2015),
    PARTITION p3 VALUES LESS THAN (2016)
);
```